# Unable to get sum of column in datatable

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I'm trying to write a method that returns me the sum of a column from entries between two dates. However it keeps returning a `DBnull` no matter what. I have other similar methods that work when the queries are simpler (no SUM, simple `select * where statement`). `performQuery()` is just helper method that returns a filled `datatable` with the query results.

```
    public static int getBookedQuantity(int shopID, int bikeID, DateTime datetime)
    {
        string query = "SELECT sum(quantity) as \"quantity\" FROM booking WHERE bikeID=@bikeID AND shopID = @shopID AND starttime >= @Datetime AND endtime < @Datetime";
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@bikeID", bikeID);
        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@shopID", shopID);
        SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@Datetime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        param3.Value = datetime;
        DataTable bookingData = performQuery(query, param1, param2, param3);
        DataRow[] row = bookingData.Select();
        int totalBooked = 0;
        if ((row.Count()) > 0 && (bookingData != null)) // if there are rows returned
            totalBooked = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]["quantity"]);
        return totalBooked;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: FYI: in SQL, `1 + 2 + NULL` yields `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying query to

```
string query = "SELECT sum(quantity) as 'quantity' FROM booking WHERE bikeID=@bikeID AND shopID = @shopID AND starttime >= @Datetime AND endtime < @Datetime";
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTable is not a correct way to get the sum. To fix your problem you have to do this:

```
var sum = Convert.ToInt32(bookingData.Rows[0]["quantity"]);
return sum;
```

But, the correct way to execute this command, is this:

```
var statement = "SELECT COUNT(*) ...";
var command = new SqlCommand(statement, connection);
command.AddParam(param1);
command.AddParam(param2);
command.AddParam(param3);
var sum = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
return sum;
```

Please, refer to MSDN doc about scalar: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this can help.

Comment: What if my query uses SELECT *, and then I use the datatable.select() method to get my sum? Is that viable?

Comment: No, the case is different. In your example code you have to bring only the sum and the correct way is ExecuteScaler because it perform very well. Anyway you can use the databale but the invocation of "Select" method is not necessary until you need to apply a filter expression (have you seen the MSDN doc about this topic?) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx